# How to remove last to string in SQL before dash

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have the following two strings:

```
hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2010-05032017-20
hcg.com.ph?C402-1B-2010-05032017-1
```

I want to get them in the form:

```
hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2010-05032017
hcg.com.ph?C402-1B-2010-05032017
```

I tried using `Left(bcode,29)`, but I think it's wrong because it's not same number of characters.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with string manipulations:

```
select left(bcode, len(bcode) - charindex('-', reverse(bcode)))
```