# Using Split in Vb.net in last dash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, split

i have two example

> "hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2012-06132017-22"
>
> "hcg.com.?C3032-1B-2012-06132017-1"

output should be

> hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2012-06132017
>
> hcg.com.?C3032-1B-2012-06132017

but i got

> hcg.com.ph?C402 and hcg.com.?C3032
>
> Dim FinalSplt() As String
>   Dim ItemBaseCode As String
>
> FinalSplt = value.ToString.Split("-")
>
> ItemBaseCode = FinalSplt(0)

How to split in the last dash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove last to string in sql before dash ..... in vb.net sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534449/how-to-remove-last-to-string-in-sql-before-dash-in-vb-net-sql)

Comment: the other one is for sqlserver this is for vb.net

Comment: Try to use .LastIndexOf()

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that uses Substring and LastIndexOf.

```
    'test input
    Dim si() As String = {"hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2012-06132017-22", "hcg.com.?C3032-1B-2012-06132017-1"}

    'use to verify
    Dim sv() As String = {"hcg.com.ph?C402-10A-2012-06132017", "hcg.com.?C3032-1B-2012-06132017"}

    For x As Integer = 0 To si.Length - 1
        Dim s As String = si(x).Substring(0, si(x).LastIndexOf("-"c))
        'verify
        If s = sv(x) Then
            Stop 'verified
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. it help me a lot

Answer (score -1):

Ok, without actually writing code I can see you need to split the string more efficiently.

Firstly, strip the quotes.

Secondly, split the string based on the `?` mark.

Take the second string in the array, and split that based on the `-` mark.

Now you have an array of all the portions, join this array with all except the last element.

Join the new string with the original first part.

Add the quotes back if needed.

Comment: Could you write it .. because im not familiar with split using array

Comment: [MSDN String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)